# Set custom home layout in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

How to set a custom layout instead home layout? The layout defines via XML.
I tried so, but the app crashes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="MyStyle" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="homeLayout">@layout/custom_home</item>
    <item name="android:homeLayout">@layout/custom_home</item>
</style>
```

Comment: can you also post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change home layout. Although `android:homeLayout` item is exposed via the API you can't touch it without causing a crash. Even if you set it to `@null` value it will not change.

I think it is present in the API by mistake. Because internally the layout is always casted to `HomeView` which is a private layout extending `FrameLayout`.

Do not ever change `android:homeLayout`! If you want to have different home layout, hide it and create custom view instead.